# Codeigniter 3 Active Record double quotes

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I having problems with Codeigniter Active Record Class with the sqlsrv driver. When I use specific join conditions or functions on the select clause, Codeigniter puts double quotes that causes errors with SQL SERVER 2012. Ex:

```
    $this->db->select('data,tab,tma');
    $this->db->from('abHistorico as ab');
    $this->db->join('tmap','ab.id_fila = tmap.id_fila AND ab.data BETWEEN data_inicial AND data_final','LEFT');
    $this->db->where('data BETWEEN "$date_star" AND "$date_end"');
```

On these case SQL SERVER throw the following error:

Incorrct sintax near 'BETWEEN'
SELECT "data", "tab", "tma" FROM "abHistorico" as "ab" LEFT JOIN "tmap" ON "ab"."id_fila" = "tmap"."id_fila" AND "ab"."data" "BETWEEN" "data_inicial" AND data_final WHERE data BETWEEN "$date_star" AND "$date_end"

As you can see BETWEEN have double quotes. I can use a third false parameter, but it's quite anoying to put in every single method from Active Record. Another example is using a function in the select clause, like CONVERT(varchar(10),data,103) or something alike.

I am concerned to disable escape but to me it's a necessity to things work properly.
I am using: PHP 5.5, SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: With CI 2.x I didn't have this problem, but now I'm migrathing to CI 3.x and it happens exactly the same. Did you solved it?

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want double quotes then

```
try like this 

$this->db->select('data,tab,tma');
    $this->db->from('abHistorico as ab');
    $this->db->join('tmap','ab.id_fila = tmap.id_fila AND ab.data BETWEEN data_inicial AND data_final','LEFT');
    $this->db->where('data BETWEEN '.$date_star.' AND '.$date_end.');
```

Comment: bad idea. sql-injection possible.